# systemd ExecStopPost and $SERVICE_RESULT behavior

Tags: linux, systemd, services, yocto

I want the not working part to work as expected. The syntax expects at least single spacing before and after the environment variable $SERVICE_RESULT.

Systemd version: 237

The failurehandler@.service template uses %i and I invoke a small utility that parses %i using "_" to segregate the service name that failed (%N) and then the corresponding $SERVICE_RESULT. I tried injecting $SERVICE_RESULT into child using PassEnvironment but that didn't help.

```
// works
ExecStopPost=/bin/echo $SERVICE_RESULT

// works
ExecStopPost=/bin/systemctl start failurehandler@%N $SERVICE_RESULT .service

// doesn't work. I want this working to later use the %N and the $SERVICE_RESULT 
ExecStopPost=/bin/systemctl start failurehandler@%N_$SERVICE_RESULT.service
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have an earlier version of systemd so I cannot test exactly what you do, but in general you can get variables interpolated by systemd by using the form `${var}` rather than the shell form `$var`. Try

```
ExecStopPost=/bin/systemctl start failurehandler@%N_${SERVICE_RESULT}.service
```